# Using Distinct with *

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I am having a problem using distinct with *. I have a table that as a join and I am trying to do a statement like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, * FROM table_a JOIN table_a.id=table_b.id WHERE status=1
```

But it is not allowing me to do so. Is there a way of using Distinct with * option?

Comment: Which SQL dialect are we talking about? Also, are you sure the DISTINCT is the problem and not the `Name, *` part?

Comment: Why is this tagged both `mysql` and `postgresql`?

Comment: I am doing this for both mysql and postgresql. I have the tables joined on id and it is the only duplicated field yet is throws an error

Comment: The error message is ; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM

Comment: `DISTINCT *` does not make any sense. That will include the primary key column(s) and so by defintion all rows will be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to test this right now, but I suspect that the problem is not with `distinct` but rather that you have columns in each table with the same names (like `id`) and it doesn't know which of the two conflicting columns to choose.  Does it change if you do `select distinct table_a.*, table_b.* ...`?

Comment: Using select distinct table_a.*, table_b.* it no longer produces an error but when I do that, distinct also does not work

Comment: @Devin -- then choose the columns that you want to choose distinctly and list them instead of using `*`.

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT *` probably will return all rows, because they are distinct:-)

To get all different names use `DISTINCT name` or to retrieve some statistics about names (e.g. count) use `SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM ... GROUP BY name`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do.

Maybe you want to return only one column with a given name (not two id columns).

In this case the standard SQL query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a JOIN table_b USING (id) WHERE status=1
```

The keyword DISTINCT means that after performing the select, duplicate rows are eliminated (not duplicate column names).

Answer (score 0):

Basically the solution is more like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a, table_b
JOIN table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY table_a.name
```

This is useful, if you want to avoid the enumeration of attributes. When you do, and the relation changes (one attribute is removed or added), your query will not work.

Read this: [MySQL 8.3.1.13. DISTINCT Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Comment: This is a very old question! Your syntax is not valid (hint: shouldn't your `FROM` clause include a table named `table_b`?) I suspect the answer was `SELECT * FROM table_a NATURAL JOIN table_b WHERE status = 1;`

Comment: @onedaywhen: Sorry, I've just revised the missing lexical. What do you mean on the answer? The accepted answer is not working, and it does not solve the problem with `DISTINCT` when you use `*`.

Comment: Your revised query returns duplicate columns. I can only guess, of course, but I think the OP wanted distinct columns (rather than distinct rows) and `NATURAL JOIN` is a good way to achieve that.